# How to handle several inquiries about connected components in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Suppose there is a connected undirected graph $V$ with $m$ edges and there are $n$ queries that what is the maximum number of connected vertices using edge no greater than $a_i$. We can assume that $n=O(m)$.

My thoughts is that running DFS $n$ times which takes $O(nm)=O(m^2)$ time. Is there a more efficient algorithm, e.g. runs in $O(m\log m)$ time?

P.S. $V$ is also a weighted graph and $a_i$ means weight.

Comment: @PSPACE-Hard sorry I forgot to mention that $V$ is a weighted graph, and $a_i$ means weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what the question is, but if you want to know the size of the largest component using only the $k$ cheapest edges for each $k$, you can sort the edges by cost and then add edges one by one starting from the empty graph, using a union-find structure to keep track of the components. This is $O(m\log m)$.

Comment: I have edited the problem and I think this is what I wanted, thanks.